# Is there a way to find active users in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find the total count of active users in a database. "Active" users here as defined as those who have registered an event on the selected day or later than the selected day. So if a user registered an event on days 1, 2 and 5, they are counted as "active" throughout days 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

My original dataset looks like this (note that this is a sample - the real dataset will run to up to 365 days, and has around 1000 users).

```
Day    ID
0      1
0      2
0      3
0      4
0      5
1      1
1      2
2      1
3      1
4      1
4      2
```

As you can see, all 5 IDs are active on Day `0`, and 2 IDs (`1` and `2`) are active until Day `4`, so I'd like the finished table to look like this:

```
Day    Count
0      5
1      2
2      2
3      2
4      2
```

I've tried using the following query:

```
select Day as days, sum(case when Day <= days then 1 else 0 end)
from df
```

But it gives incorrect output (only counts users who were active on each specific days).

I'm at a loss as to what I could try next. Does anyone have any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would just use `generate_series()`:

```
select gs.d, count(*)
from (select id, min(day) as min_day, max(day) as max_day
      from t
      group by id
     ) t cross join lateral
     generate_series(t.min_day, .max_day, 1) gs(d)
group by gs.d
order by gs.d;
```

If you want to count *everyone* as active from day 1 -- but not all have a value on day 1 -- then use `1` instead of `min_day`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2b7a37dcdb50ba76b76ea8a3707248e7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with `generate_series()` (or `lateral` for that matter); this looks like it could be a good solution. One thing: I'm getting the error message "`Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "1"`". I can't see the typo, would you mind helping check it?

Comment: @fpl . . . There was a syntax error in the column definitions.  I've included a db<>fiddle, to show that this works.

Comment: Thank you, looks great! Wow, I hadn't used fiddle before either. So much to learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

A bit verbose, but this should do:

```
with dt as (
        select 0 d, 1 id
        union all
        select 0 d, 2 id
        union all
        select 0 d, 3 id
        union all
        select 0 d, 4 id
        union all
        select 0 d, 5 id
        union all
        select 1 d, 1 id
        union all
        select 1 d, 2 id
        union all
        select 2 d, 1 id
        union all
        select 3 d, 1 id
        union all
        select 4 d, 1 id
        union all
        select 4 d, 2 id
)
, active_periods as (
        select id
                , min(d) min_d
                , max(d) max_d
        from dt
        group by id
)
, days as (
        select distinct d
        from dt
)
select d.d
        , count(ap.id)
from days d
join active_periods ap on d.d between ap.min_d and ap.max_d
group by 1
order by 1 asc
```

Comment: Thanks @Georgi. This works, but actually the data given was just a sample set. I'll actually need to run it on time periods of up to 365 days, and update automatically as the days pass, so unfortunately it is not practical :-( Apologies as I should perhaps have mentioned this in the question.

Comment: Following your logic, you will have to update all 365 days daily, so I don't really see the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You need count by day.

```
select
    id,
    count(*)
from df
GROUP BY
    id
```